# Join that returns always 1 record

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table that holds tests. For every test you have a generic one (TYPE field is NULL) but for some tests you can have also more specific tests (TYPE field has a value).

I need a join to this table on the test and type but so that if no type is specified I get the generic tests (That is no problem as both sides have NULL) but if a type is specified I get the test of that type if there is one, or the generic test when there exist no specific one.

```
    TestTable
    ... Test   Grp  Type  Description ...
    ... TestA  G1   NULL  TestA_Gen    ...
    ... TestA  G1   M     TestA_M     ...
    ... TestB  G1   NULL  TestB_Gen   ...
    ... TestB  G1   X     TestB_X     ...

    BaseTable
    ... Pers  Type ...
    ... P_A   Null ...
    ... P_B   M    ...
    ... P_C   X    ...

Select B.PERS, T.DESCRIPTION
from BaseTable B
Join Testtable T on ??? and T.Grp = 'G1'

should give
P_A TestA_Gen
P_A TestB_Gen
P_B TestA_M
P_B TestB_Gen
P_C TestA_Gen
P_C TestB_X
```

How do I do that in MySQL?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

According to given sample data there is "Type" which is common in both table

```
Select B.PERS, T.DESC
from BaseTable B
right outer Join Testtable T 
on ( T.type is null or B.Type=T.type or B.Type is null)
and T.Grp = 'G1' 
where T.DESC<>'' 
order by B.PERS asc
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had some notification of the answers.

Comment: This query is not correct. It returns more records than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple:

```
SELECT 
    b.pers,
    t.description
FROM
    BaseTable AS b
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT test 
      FROM TestTable
      WHERE grp = 'G1'
    ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN 
    TestTable AS ti
      ON  ti.grp = 'G1'
      AND ti.test = d.test
      AND ti.type = b.type
  LEFT JOIN 
    TestTable AS t
      ON  t.grp = 'G1'
      AND t.test = d.test
      AND t.type <=> ti.type 
ORDER BY 
    b.pers,
    d.test ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eb92/19)

---

Another way, similar to the above in logic but with different join syntax:

```
SELECT 
    b.pers,
    t.description
FROM
    BaseTable AS b
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT test 
      FROM TestTable
      WHERE grp = 'G1'
    ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN 
    TestTable AS t
      ON  t.grp = 'G1'
      AND t.test = d.test
      AND t.type <=> 
          ( SELECT ti.type
            FROM TestTable AS ti
            WHERE ti.grp = 'G1'
              AND ti.test = d.test
              AND ti.type = b.type
       --   ORDER BY (ti.type IS NULL)
              LIMIT 1
          ) 
ORDER BY 
    b.pers,
    d.test ;
```